# Maximum utilization of a vehicle. Finding max value from 2 arrays

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, merge

I am trying to solve a simple optimization problem and have proposed solution. Just wondering if it is correct or not. Here is the problem description

There is a vehicle that can travel a total certain max distance say 3000 miles as an example, after which it needs servicing. There are 2 arrays, one `outgoing` array and one `returning` array. Each array element denotes distance. I have to come up with 2 numbers one from `outgoing` array and another from `incoming` array that makes maximum utilization of the vehicle. Say if I can use total distance 3000, it is the best or the one closest to it. I have written a program for it and was hoping if I could get input from others if it is correct or has a flaw.

```
public class Vehicle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] outgoing = {2710,300,2500,2800,700};
        Integer[] returning = {2200,289,490};
        int l1=0,l2=0;
        Arrays.sort(outgoing, Collections.reverseOrder());
        Arrays.sort(returning);
        int range = 3000;
        int max = 0;
        int out = 0;
        int ret = 0;
        while(l1<outgoing.length && l2<returning.length) {
            int sum = outgoing[l1]+returning[l2];
           if (sum<=range && sum>max) {
               max = sum;
               out = outgoing[l1];
               ret = returning[l2];
           }
           if(sum>range) {
               l1++;
           } else {
               l2++;
           }
        }
        System.out.println(max);
        System.out.println(out);
        System.out.println(ret);
    }
}
```

The approach I am taking is that I sort `outgoing` array in reverse order and `returning` in natural order. Then I try to find the max sum that is possible by picking one element from each array. If the temp sum exceeds the max distance allowed, I move the pointer of the array that is in descending order else I move the pointer of the array that is in ascending order.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you try and edit the answer and clarify? You want the cars which should go to service soon?

Comment: To explain it more clearly, there is a fleet of cars that is not much relevant to the part of Q. But when a car is picked for delivery, it has a constraint of maximum distance it can travel without being services. So, the goal is that given a car from the fleet with travel  distance constraint, what journey should the car take for outgoing and return paths. Does that help? Basically pick an outgoing distance and return distance so that car can be utilized to max given the max travel dist constraint of the car

Answer (score 0):

What I understand reading your description is that we have to find the maximum summation of two integer numbers which is less than or equal to `range` and, one integer number is taken from `outgoing` array and another is taken from `returning` array.

Recently, I have solved similar problem in [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/electronics-shop/problem) and wrote an editorial on it [here](https://bishalg.blogspot.com/2018/09/two-pointers-technique-binary-search.html). So, your approach is similar to the approach number - 3 described in the editorial. So, It is a correct approach.